# aes decryption \0 character ios

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

i've a problem..when i decrypt the data that is returned from my php page,
if the length of the string is less than 16, the char \0 is append to string. 
Original string is: **100000065912248**
I decrypt the encrypted string with this function:

```
#define FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM     kCCAlgorithmAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE    kCCBlockSizeAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE      kCCKeySizeAES256

+ (NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv;
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    // setup key
    unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
    bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
    [key getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];

    // setup iv
    char cIv[FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    bzero(cIv, FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (iv) {
        [iv getBytes:cIv length:FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    }

    // setup output buffer
    size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    int length = [data length];

    // do decrypt
    size_t decryptedSize = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                          0,
                                          cKey,
                                          FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                          cIv,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          [data length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &decryptedSize);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
    } else {
        free(buffer);
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I send a nil "iv" parameter to the function and after i use "cIv" in function, and it contain this:
[image: cIv description]

The result is exactly, but the length of string is 16 instead of 15 (string: 100000065912248). In fact, the last character is \0.

Why? how can i solve?

EDIT:

PHP encrypt function:

```
function encrypt($plaintext) {

    $key = 'a16byteslongkey!a16byteslongkey!';

    $base64encoded_ciphertext = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
    $base64encoded_ciphertext = trim($base64encoded_ciphertext);

    return $base64encoded_ciphertext;
}
```

Comment: In general `trim` on ciphertext` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES is a block cypher and encrypts/decrypts blocks of length 128 bits (16 bytes). So if the data is not a block size some padding must be added. The most popular and supported by Apple is PKCS7.

Interfacing with PHP one must consider padding and possible base64 encoding.

The solution is to use the same padding on both sides, PHP and iOS.

AES always operates on 16 bytes, there is no option--so, if you have 15 bytes a byte is going to have to be added, that is padding. From what I understand (not much about PHP encryption) PHP does not do true PCKS7padding and it is best to pad yourself. Lookup PKCS7 in Wikipedia.

Comment: but my function in php don't use padding (i have edited post with php function)

Comment: AES in ECB/CBC mode *normally* uses padding. Streaming modes don't require padding, and ECB/CBC may deploy ciphertext stealing. AES as a block cipher does always operate on 16 bytes, but you may still choose a mode that doesn't require padding.

Comment: @owlstead while streaming mode are good in some situations and look very attractive they are very hard to get correct: never using the same nonce, etc. Thus I personally don't recommend them.

Comment: I'm not criticizing the answer (i voted up) but I just wanted to point out that the need for padding is dependent on the block cipher mode, not the cipher itself.

Comment: @owlstead I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be OK with zero padding (the default) if you only operate on strings, but I would recommend PKCS#7 padding, if only for interoperability reasons.

With zero padding the plaintext is padded with `00` valued bytes, but only if required. This is different from PKCS#7 padding, which is always deployed. After decryption you can use the `trim` function on the *resulting plaintext* after decryption. You should then get the original string.

This obviously wont work on binary data because it may end with a character that is removed by the `trim` function. Beware that `trim` in PHP seems to strip off `00` bytes. This is not a given, officially `00` is not whitespace, even though it is treated that way by many runtimes.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove padding from the decrypted data

```
function removePadding($decryptedText){
    $strPad = ord($decryptedText[strlen($decryptedText)-1]);
    $decryptedText= substr($decryptedText, 0, -$strPad);
    return $decryptedText;
}
```

Comment: The answer code will not work with null padding which PHP mcrypt defaults to and that is what the OP is using. For PKCS#7/PKCS#5 padding there needs to be a check that the padding is valid. Consider use of the wrong key, `$strPad` most likely would be wrong, potentially a value larger than the length of the data. But do not return a *bad padding error*, that tends to create a padding oracle, instead just do nothing. Most libraries support PKCS#7 padding and will automatically add padding on encryption and removed the padding on decryption–nothing more needs be done.